# Cigarette Emissive Lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, emission

I’m trying to make a bit of an ominous render in which my character has a cigarette in his mouth and I want his face to be lit by that and the rest of the scene dark.

I’m using this model as a place holder for a proof of concept   https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/cigarette-daily3d-eff40b1550e0466a9c3273a519139143

Any clues as to how I can achieve this? I’m using cycles at the moment with an emissive shader node but…. Not great. Wondering if I need to add some fog or something.

Just curious if either of you have rendered something like this in your past

Comment: This cigarette model that you linked is over 1800 meters long. Yeah, over a mile! Be careful when you import it  --A while ago I did something similar to what you described. So I composed a scene to see what this would look like. Well,  you can always add an extra light if the emission shader is not strong enough and use the compositor for post-render effects. Without smoke, there seems to be something missing. I would definitely add it.

Comment: Hahah yeah it’s quite the cigarette that’s for sure! Ok I will add some smoke hopefully that helps it a bit and maybe some really dim lighting

Comment: Maybe post a screenshot and describe what you don't like?